# How to push without a pull?

Tags: git

I and another one is working on a project component.

We used to push and pull and so on. Once I create a new copy of that project without pull from remote repository and made many changes in it.

Now I can't push it to remote repository.

It complaints that pull before push like that..

Are there any other ways to resolve it?
Or do I need to pull and copy and paste all those changes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can instead replay your local commits on top of what you would pull

```
git pull --rebase
```

Then you will be able to push without any issue

[image: https://gitmap.files.wordpress.com/2010/12/pull-rebase.png?w=620]

<sup>([Image from gitmap: "Learning GIT"](https://gitmap.wordpress.com/))</sup>

See also "[Why one should use ‘`git pull`’ command with ‘`rebase`’ option.](http://code4reference.com/2013/06/why-one-should-use-git-pull-command-with-rebase-option/)":

[image: http://code4reference.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/git-pull-rebase1-e1371538599469.jpg]

Comment: It complaints fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Comment: @Veena In which folder are you doing this command? It is supposed to run in the repo folder (the one which includes a `.git/` subfolder). Not in the `.git/` folder directly.

Comment: E:\DataCollectionje_connected_4_git is my directory which contains the project.. But there is no any .git file.. should I include it using git init?

Comment: @Veena yes, but only after completing https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1, and only after reading at least chapter 2 (http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository)

Answer (score 1):

The question should not be how to push without pull but how to pull without copy pasting changes, because this is never necessary.

The default setting when you pull after you made changes is that the remote changes are merged. An alternative is to rebase with `git pull --rebase` which results in a cleaner history: your changes are applied on top of the remote changes.

In both cases you have to commit all your changes first, with uncommitted changes it won't work. Also you might get conflicts if both of you edited files in the same places. If you use a graphical git client, it will help you to resolve the conflicts, otherwise search for "resolve git merge conflicts" to learn more.